# Set 'Local Group Policy Editor' settings from command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, group-policy

Some things are set through the `Local Group Policy Editor`.

Is there a way to set using the command line or batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to change group policy from the command line? Use LGPO.exe tool to check.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/

There is some command that you can use for do many group policy tasks.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

If it's only Administrative Templates settings, the easiest way is to replace the registry.pol
files (%Systemroot%\System32\GroupPolicy\ and %Systemroot%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers)

Comment: "There is some command that you can use for do many group policy tasks." - Which command?  Why does your answer itself not include the relevant information?  There are about 20 Cmdlets, so which command, are you indicating to the author is relevant?  You should edit and improve this answer.